# Errors while booting into Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.10 on Dell Vostro 15 3000 (3581)?

Tags: boot, dell, dell-vostro, elantech

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.10 on my Vostro 15 3000 (3581) Notebook via a bootable USB drive created with `rufus`, and I am getting errors. I had no issues with Arch-based distros but every Debian-based distro gives me this error. My machine boots up, but it works slower and laggier compared to Windows 11 and Arch-based distros.

What could be the reason, and how can I fix them?

Error screen shot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrVM7.jpg) and [more here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvanQ.jpg)

Comment: Does the machine boot you can login and everything works? If so ignore the INFORMATION messages. This is a know issue being worked on.

Comment: Yes @David boots but it's too slow

Comment: Same errors in second screen same comment. These errors do not make it slow.